# Git: list all hosted repositories on an origin

Tags: git, macos

I have several repositories hosted on a Mac OS X Xcode server on the other side of the room.

On said aforementioned server, I need to connect to it through https and connect to one of them or two of them.

How do I fetch or supply a list of the repositories hosted on the origin so that I know the paths to the repositories I would like to connect to?

From my Mac, how to I ask the git origin server on the other side of the room to tell me the name of all the repositories that are sitting there?

Myself and other people will be accessing it and creating repos, so I need to have a list of repos and URLs for those repos so that people can connect to them.

Comment: For gitolite you can simply ssh to your server to get a list of managed repositories. No idea about Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

You need a listener to be in front of Git and its repo in order to tell you more.
Git alone does not keep track of repo, it only access them and allows for cloning/pulling/pushing.

That listener can be as basic as an [authorization layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#access-control) like [Gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html), or as sophisticated as a full-fledged repository hosting service like:

- [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/) (ruby)
- [Gogs](https://gogs.io/) (Go)
- [Gitblit](http://gitblit.com/) (java)

Those services do display the full list of repos at a remote side.